# Derivation of an identity in HMM model

Tags: probability, machine-learning, conditional-probability

### Problem

In HMM model, the forward and backward probability is defined as
$$
\begin{aligned}
\alpha_t(i) &= \Pr(o_1,\cdots, o_t, i_t=q_i\vert \lambda)\\
\beta_t(i) &= \Pr(o_{t+1},\cdots, o_T\vert i_t=q_i,\lambda)
\end{aligned}
$$
where $o_i$ is observation, $i_t$ is state and $\lambda$ is HMM model parameter.

One commonly used identity is 
$$
\alpha_t(i)\beta_t(i)=\Pr(i_t=q_i, o_1,\cdots,o_t,\cdots, o_T\vert \lambda)
$$
However, I am not sure how this is derived. Specifically, I do not know how to combine two events $o_1,\cdots,o_t$ and $o_{t+1},\cdots,o_T$ into one $o_1,\cdots, o_T$.

Could anyone help me, thank you in advance.

### Edit

Sorry I did not specify what is $\lambda$, the book I read define it as a triplet
$$
\lambda = (\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B},\mathbf{\pi})
$$
where $\mathbf{A}$ is the state transition matrix, $\mathbf{B}$ is the observation matrix and $\mathbf{\pi}$ is the initial state probability vector. More specifically,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{A}_{ij}&=\Pr(i_{t+1}=q_j\vert i_t=q_i)\\
\mathbf{B}_{jk}&=\Pr(o_t=v_k\vert i_t=q_i)\\
\mathbf{\pi}_i&=\Pr(i_1=q_i)
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Is the "HMM model parameter" $\ \lambda\ $ merely the set of initial state, transition and emission probabilites? If not, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer, we’ll assume that $\lambda$ is a collection of deterministic parameters that specify the HMM (but this needs to be clarified in the question). First, notice that
\begin{align}
\beta_t(i) &= \Pr(o_{t+1},\cdots, o_T\vert i_t=q_i,\lambda) \\
&= \Pr(o_{t+1},\cdots, o_T\vert i_t=q_i, o_1,\cdots,o_t, \lambda)
\end{align}
because the observations from time $t+1$ to $T$ are independent from past observations. This is an assumption in the HMM model, which can be seen when looking at [the graph structure of states and observations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model#/media/File:Hmm_temporal_bayesian_net.svg), where no connections are drawn between the observations, so that the observations depend only on states and not on each other.

Also, recall that
$$\Pr(x,y|\lambda) = \Pr(y|x, \lambda)\Pr(x|\lambda),$$
for any random variables $x$, $y$, and $\lambda$, which is a basic property of conditional probability  (although $\lambda$ is assumed not to be a random variable in our setting). Applying this property, we have
\begin{align}
\Pr(i_t=q_i, o_1,\cdots,o_t,\cdots, o_T\vert \lambda) &= \Pr(o_{t+1},\cdots, o_T\vert i_t=q_i, o_1,\cdots,o_t, \lambda)\Pr(i_t=q_i, o_1,\cdots, o_t \vert \lambda).
\end{align}
Substitute the above equation for $\beta_t(i)$ to get
$$\beta_t(i)\Pr(i_t=q_i, o_1,\cdots, o_t \vert \lambda).$$
Substitute your equation for $\alpha_t(i)$ to get $\beta_t(i)\alpha_t(i)$.

Comment: This seems to me to make an implicit (though certainly reasonable) assumption which is not clearly spelt out in the OP's question.  If $\ \lambda\ $ is a random variable, and the distribution of the observations *unconditioned* on $\ \lambda\ $ satisfy the assumptions of a Hidden Markov model, then their distribution *conditional on* $\ \lambda\ $ will *not* necessarily do so (Suppose, for example that $\ \lambda\ $ is the sum of the observations), so this must be assumed if the statement for which the OP wants a proof is to be true in general.

Comment: As indicated by the query in my comment above, though, I suspect that $\ \lambda\ $ is not, in fact, necessarily a random variable at all, but the collection of parameter values that specify the details of the model.  Some expositions of the theory of these models ([this one](https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/A.pdf), for example), do insert a symbol representing these parameters as an apparent "condition" into all the probabilities calculated from the model they specify. In this case, of course, $\ \lambda\ $ can be effectively dealt with in the way your answer does.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera I agree with all of your points. My approach can’t be applied until the definition of $\lambda$ is clarified.